Problems with booting
I'm having trouble booting Ubuntu on my machine. Initially I had a problem with full disk. I installed "Linux File Systems For Windows" and deleted some heavy files (I'm with a dual boot machine with windows and Ubuntu). Now I'm having this problem.
[FAILED] Failed to start GNOME Display System.
Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
What should I do?
Image of problem on booting terminal

Are you able to switch to a CLI virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F6 for example) and log in there? if so, please run the suggested systemctl status gdm.service and possibly journalctl -xeu gdm.service. Can you be more specific about what files you deleted?

Your question is quite confusing. How did the WSL allow you to delete files from an installed Ubuntu that was installed to the disk outside the WSL? Please edit the question and state exactly what your configuration is.
